Why do I get two different results to the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos{x}}{1+x^2}dx}$?
I know that the correct result to the integral is $\frac{\pi}{e}$ and I know how to arrive at it by for example defining $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{1+z^2}$ and then taking the real part of the result of the integral along a semicircle in the upper half plane. The problem I have is that if instead of defining the function as above I say that $f(z)=\frac{\cos{z}}{1+z^2}$ and use the identity $\cos{z}=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ to calculate the corresponding residue together with a semicircular contour in the upper half plane I get $\frac{\pi}{2}[\frac{1}{e}+e]$ as a result:
Define $f(z)=\frac{\cos{z}}{1+z^2}$ and the contour $C$ as the closed, positively oriented semicircle with radius $R$ (including the segment $[−R,R]$ on the real axis). Let the semicircular arc be called $\Gamma$. Thus:
$$\int_{C}{f(z)dz}=\int_{\Gamma}{f(z)dz} + \int_{-R}^{R}{f(z)dz}=2\pi i Res(f, z=i), $$
were the rightmost result stems from the residue theorem and the fact that the only pole in $C$ is $z=i$. Taking the limit as $R$  goes to infinity we see that the integral over $\Gamma$ vanishes and were left with:
$$\int_{C}{f(z)dz}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(z)dz}=2\pi i Res(f, z=i). $$
The function has a simple pole at $z=i$ by which it follows that:
$$ Res(f, z=i)=\lim_{z\to i}{(z-i)\frac{\cos{z}}{1+z^2}}=\lim_{z\to i}{\frac{\cos{z}}{z+i}} \\ =\lim_{z \to i} {\frac{1}{2(z+i)}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})}=\frac{1}{4i}(\frac{1}{e}+e).$$
Thus:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{f(z)dz}=2\pi i (\frac{1}{4i}(\frac{1}{e}+e)) = \frac{\pi}{2}[\frac{1}{e}+e]. $$
Why does this result differ from the correct one even though I just use a different function to start of? Does it have something to do with the behaviour of $\cos{z}$ in the complex plane?

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: look at the $R\to\infty$ behaviour of $\left|e^{\pm iRe^{i\theta}}\right|$ for $\theta\in[0,,\pi]$.

With $e^{-iz}$ we probably need to use lower half plane, don't we?

To evaluate an integral on real axis by completing real axis to a closed contour and taking residue, you need to justify the contribution from the extra piece of contour your added vanishes. $e^{-iz}$ blows up on upper plane, so its contribution on the upper semi-circle doesn't vanish as $R \to \infty$.

First of all thank you all very much, J.G. for the hint (and welcoming me! Happy to be here!), @SineoftheTime for the edit , and achille hui for the explanation! I falsely assumed the Integral over $\Gamma$ would vanish but it obviously doesn't like you all pointed out. Once again, thank you all very much, now I finally understand my mistake!

@RoyaleFighter01 if you want, you can answer your own question below.

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2} d x=\frac{1}{2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{x i}+e^{-x i}}{1+x^2} d x= \frac{1}{2}  \left[\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{x i}}{1+x^2}}_J d x+\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x i}}{1+x^2}}_K dx\right]
$$
We can evaluate the integral $J$ using contour integration along anti-clockwise direction of the upper semi-circle
$$\gamma=\gamma_{1} \cup \gamma_{2} \textrm{ where }  \gamma_{1}(t)=t+i 0(-R \leq t \leq R)  \textrm{ and } \gamma_{2}(t)=R e^{i t}  (0<t<\pi) $$
$$
\begin{aligned}
J= &\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{x i}}{1+x^2} d x \\=& \oint_\gamma \frac{e^{z i}}{1+z^2} d z \\
= & 2 \pi i \cdot \frac{e^{i \cdot i}}{2 i} \\
= & \frac{\pi}{ e}
\end{aligned}
$$
As suggested by @achille hui, we can’t use $\gamma$ for $K$. Instead, we could evaluate $K$ using contour integration along anti-clockwise direction of the lower semi-circle $$\beta=\beta_{1} \cup \beta_{2} \textrm{ where }  \beta_{1}(t)=t+i 0(-R \leq t \leq R)  \textrm{ and } \beta_{2}(t)=R e^{i t}  (\pi<t<2\pi) $$
$$
\begin{aligned}
K & =- \oint_\beta \frac{e^{-z i}}{1+z^2} d z=-\left[2 \pi i \lim _{z \rightarrow-i}(z+i) \frac{e^{-z i}}{z^2+1}\right] \\
& =-\left[2 \pi i\left(\lim _{z \rightarrow-i} \frac{e^{-z i}}{z-i}\right)\right]=-2 \pi i \frac{e^{-1}}{-2 i}=\frac{\pi}{e} 
\end{aligned}
$$
Putting back yields
$$\boxed{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2} d x =\frac{\pi}{e}  }$$

On the other hand, we can get the same answer using $\cos x=\Re e^{ix}$ as below:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{1+x^2} d x 
= \Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{x i}}{1+x^2} d x 
= \frac{\pi}{e}
$$
